# How to detect javascript of chrome browser is disabled in chrome-extension application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have added the following code in chrome extension app. this noScript block will be executed when the the javascript is disable in browser. Following is my snippet.:

Following is my code snippet.:

```
 <noscript>
    <div id="nojs">
        <div
                class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="z-index: 1040;"></div>
        <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="modal"
             style="z-index: 1050; display: block; top:26%;">
            <div
                    class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content
smsUser_modalContent">
                    <div class="modal-header"
                         style="background-color: #428bca"><h4
                            class="modal-title">Information</h4></div>
                    <div class="modal-body smsUser"><p>Warning:
                        Either you have javascript disabled or your browser does not support
                        javascript. To work properly, this page requires javascript to be
                        enabled.</p></div>
                    <div
                            class="modal-footer"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</noscript>
```

Comment: Please format your code. What is your question?

Comment: Extensions work fine when javascript is turned off.  You don't need that at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is working fine. Is it possible to display a message that the javascript of chrome browser is disabled/enabled in chrome-extension application? For website/web application it is working with noscript tag. but for chrome extension it is not working. Any suggestion appreciable.

Comment: [chrome.contentSettings API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-JavascriptContentSetting).

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare [`contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings) permission in your extension's manifest

   ```
   {
     "name": "My extension",
     ...
     "permissions": [
       "contentSettings"
     ],
     ...
   }
   ```
2. In event page, call [`chrome.contentSettings[type].get()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-ContentSetting) to retrieve the [javascript settings](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-JavascriptContentSetting). Many samples [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contentsettings).

   ```
   chrome.contentSettings['javascript'].get({ primaryUrl: url}, function(details) {
     const value = details.setting;
     if (value === "block") {
       // javascript is blocked
     }
   });
   ```
3. Once detecting javascript is disabled, you could use something like [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) or [Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) to tell content scripts to show HTML markups in current web page.